# How to capture the click even in WowBook

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [WowBook](http://codecanyon.net/item/wowbook-create-ebooks-with-page-flip/1791563) and need to capture the click event on the page turning link.

More specifically, when there are no more "pages" (actually DIV containers), I want to send the user to another URL. I can't find anything in the documentation. I contacted the author, but perhaps someone here has done what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Would the onShowPage method help? Assuming that you have 20 pages:

```
$("#book").wowBook({
  onShowPage : function(book, page, pageIndex){ 
    if (book.isOnPage(20)) { 
      window.location = 'new_url';
    } 
  } 
});
```

More info in the URL:
http://www.neuearbeit.de/wow_book_plugin/documentation/#onshowpage

Comment: I want to show the page itself, but have the "next" button go to the link. Thus, I need some way to capture the event that is currently disabled, since it page show is the last in the book. In your example, Page 20 would only be shown briefly, and the user would ne self-select their destination.

Answer (score 1):

From the plugin author, this works.

```
    $("#next").click(function(){
        var book = $.wowBook("#features");
        if (book.currentPage>=book.pages.length-1) {
            // redirect to google
            window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
        }
    });
```